# Java Inheritance: Why calling a method at the parent constructor level, calls the overridden child method?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

Calling the fruitName method inside Fruit constructor, is actually delegating the call to the child Apple class's method!

```
public class CallingParentMethodInInheritanceHierarchy {

abstract class Fruit {
    String fruitName;

    public Fruit(String fruitName) {
        this.fruitName = fruitName;

        /*
         * o/p - Inside constructor - Child: Fruit name is - Apple
         */
        System.out.println("Inside constructor - " + fruitName()); // doubt?
    }

    public String fruitName() {
        return "Parent: Fruit name is - " + fruitName;
    }

    public abstract String type();

}

class Apple extends Fruit {
    public Apple() {
        super("Apple");
    }

    public String fruitName() {
        /*
         * To call the super class method, only way is -
         * 
         * System.out.println(super.fruitName());
         */
        return "Child: Fruit name is - " + fruitName;
    }

    @Override
    public String type() {
        return "AllSeasonsFruit";
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Fruit fruit = new CallingParentMethodInInheritanceHierarchy().new Apple();

    /*
     * o/p - Child: Fruit name is - Apple
     */
    System.out.println(fruit.fruitName());
}
```

}

The main attempt behind this, is that I was trying to call the parent method without using the trivial way super.fruitName() call inside a child method.

Please help me @line #12

Comment: It's not trivial; it's the only way.  There's no difference in the behavior between parent and child - you're printing out the name.  Why override it?

Comment: methods called in constructors should be final.

Comment: @duffymo - I am just checking, later I can add real functionality :-)

Comment: Sorry, you either understand polymorphism or you don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is polymorphism 101. The most specific - i.e. lowest on the inheritance tree - version of a method is invoked within a class hierarchy.  If you had not overridden the fruitName() method *at all* then the base class method would be called.

Comment: But I am calling inside the parent constructor, at this time the child object would not be completely instantiated. Please help if I am wrong.

Comment: That is a different question - and it would not work the way you are trying. You are correct that the child would not yet be available. But that does not change that invoking the method would *attempt* to invoke the child. So you need to rethink your hierarchy.

Comment: @53by97 Consider this: you can already call abstract methods of `Fruit` in its constructor, and `Apple`'s code will thus be invoked. Similarly, `Apple`'s code will run in place of the overridden method.

Comment: Hey, whatever you guys are telling is fine, but still all dots are not connected. Think this way - parent class object is instantiated and it is having a fruitName method, till this point child class object is not constructed yet and we are calling this method inside parent class constructor - it should call its own method because a same method is already present in the class.

Comment: @53by97  If you want to invent your own programming paradigm then have at it. We are just relating how existing OO - as implemented in Java - works.

Comment: @53by97 If it still didn't click for you, you may try researching how OOP is implemented in Java on the lowest level. Particularly, you might want to learn about virtual method tables.

Answer (score 3):

Because that's how polymorphism works. Child classes can override any method that is not final, and parent code won't be able to tell the difference. That's why non-abstract non-final public methods are generally discouraged.

Comment: Why do you say that non-abstract non final public methods are discouraged? That's a foundation of OO design: to provide implementation but *allow* specialization when needed.

Comment: @javadba Because this violates the [Open-closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle). Implementing abstract methods instead of overriding non-abstract methods can also be used to achieve specialization, and in a much less error-prone way.

Comment: Consider the case that a default publicly accessible behavior (i.e. method)  were desired yet it should be permitted to override that behavior in subclasses. Please illustrate how that would be achieved.

Comment: @javadba By having that default behavior outside the parent class. `Dude` should not have any default behavior, instead there should be some `DefaultDude` that provides the behavior by implementing an abstract method of `Dude`. If you need to modify the `DefaultDude`, use the Decorator pattern.

Comment: OK I see. I'll buy that.

Comment: @javadba In Java, overriding a method is much simpler than delegating/decorating in terms of how much code is needed. I suppose this might be why you are advocating overriding. Lack of syntactic sugar for delegation is a flaw in Java language design, but there are syntactic constructs for delegation in other JVM languages, e.g. in Kotlin.

Comment: The DefaultFoo class approach makes sense. But it is worth noting that is not the *common* approach in Java. Instead DefaultFoo is typically used as  a convenience when there are a boatload of abstract methods to implement - and not specifically to address the "open closed principle" you mention.